# Extending real functionals to complex functionals

Tags: functional-analysis

I was reading a proof for the Hanh-Banach Separation theorem which said

> We first observe that it suffices to establish the result for real scalars. If we have done so then for $X$ a complex Banach space we may find a real-linear $\ell: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which separates $A$ and $B$ as required, and we may then set $\Lambda(x)=\ell(x)-i \ell(i x)$.

I don't understand how this extension even works since $\ell $ is not meant to even take imaginary values. I tried to play with it but I am still confused.

**Question** : Could someone elaborate on what is going on here?

**Context**:

> Theorem 2.28. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, nonempty, convex sets in a real or complex Banach space $X$.
> a) If $A$ is open, there exist $\Lambda \in X^{\prime}$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$
> \Re(\Lambda x)<\gamma \leqslant \Re(\Lambda y)
> $$
> for all $x \in A, y \in B$. If $B$ is further assumed to be open the second inequality may be taken to be strict.
> b) If $A$ is compact, $B$ is closed then there exist $\Lambda \in X^{\prime}$ and $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$
> \Re(\Lambda x)<\gamma_1<\gamma_2<\Re(\Lambda y) \text {. }
> $$
> Proof. We first observe that it suffices to establish the result for real scalars. If we have done so then for $X$ a complex Banach space we may find a real-linear $\ell: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which separates $A$ and $B$ as required, and we may then set $\Lambda(x)=\ell(x)-i \ell(i x)$.

Comment: The functional $\Lambda$ is complex valued and homogeneous with respect to real coefficients and $i.$ Therefore it is homogeneous with respect to complex coefficients. Moreover $\ell(x)={\rm Re}\,\Lambda(x).$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I see what you wrote and I agree. So we think of $\Lambda$ as an extension correct?

Comment: Exactly. The trick is to extend $\ell$ to a functional linear with respect to complex numbers, so that the real part is equal $\ell.$